# How do I split at a Regex and everything after it

Tags: python, regex

I have a Regex that successfully captures a date. Now I wanna split it so that everything after the date is also taken. I have this now:

```
data = "11/07/2020 apple\n juice\n 11/07/2020 pear"
dateRegex = re.compile('([0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+)')
splittedData = re.split(dateRegex, data)

# Splits into: ['11/07/2020', ' apple\n juice\n ', '11/07/2020' ' pear']
# Desired:     ['11/07/2020 apple\n juice\n ', '11/07/2020 pear']
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I fail to see why you don't just split on a newline then strip the elements.

Comment: Try splitting on new line.

Comment: Because there might be several newlines in the data behind 1 single date, that I all don't want to be splitted. I updated the example to make that more clear.

Comment: use `re.finditer` to locate the start points of your dates, then use this list to capture from one start up-to the next start, put an end-of-text-start-sentinel to the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
(?<=\s)(?=\d+/\d+/\d+)
```

**NOTE**: Works with `re.split` in Python 3.7 and newer where the support of splitting on a pattern that could match an empty string was added.

**Details**

- `(?<=\s)` - a location immediately preceded with a whitespace
- `(?=\d+/\d+/\d+)` - a location immediately followed with 1+ digits and two occurrences of `/` + one or more digits.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/yXDKsb):

```py
import re
data = "11/07/2020 apple\n juice\n 11/07/2020 pear"
dateRegex = re.compile('(?<=\s)(?=\d+/\d+/\d+)')
splittedData = re.split(dateRegex, data)
print(splittedData)
# => ['11/07/2020 apple\n juice\n ', '11/07/2020 pear']
```